# Error returned when running npm install on package.json which contains symbolic links

Tags: node.js

When I run npm install, I get the an error output that I'm not sure how to interpret.

A package.json was created by a colleague, and contains a path for preinstall.  He runs Mac, and I'm running Windows 7.

First, the package.json:
`{
  "name": "package name",
  "description": "description",
  "readme": "?",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "../../etc/directory_with_files"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aa-moduleName": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}`

Next, the error output:

> myApp@0.0.1 preinstall: `../../etc/directory_with_files`
>
> ../../etc/directory_with_files
>
> '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Have you tried turning the forward slashes into backslashes?

Comment: Mac OS uses *nix file paths and windows uses ... windows file paths.  So right off the bat I'd try commenting out or changing that path.  Node.js is usually pretty good about changing *nix filepath into a windows compatible path, but it might not do that in a package.json file.  Also, it has been several years since I have had to use windows cmd line, but something is tickling my memory about not being able to chain `..`.  So perhaps, `..` is valid, but `../..` is not. of course it may just be the wrong kind of slash, play around with it or just remove it.

Comment: playing around with slashes helped, but only sort of.  Now it says "..\..\etc\directory_with_files" is not recognized as an internal or external command.  Is this a symbolic link issue (just learned about symbolic links today)

Comment: Doesn't sound like it, it sounds like it doesn't recognize that command... Until someone gives you a solid answer, this is trial and error, create a test dir in your current dir and see if it lets you use that(`.\dir_with_files`), then one dir up(`..\dir_with_files`), then two(`..\..\dir_with_files`) until it breaks...

Comment: this might be a complete dead end -- since there are all these bash scripts that have to run, it seems like I need to do this under Cygwin (am I dead ended?)

Comment: Also, just gota ask, /etc is a nix file system dir, do you in fact have a dir named etc two dirs up from you current working dir?

Comment: /etc is the name of a directory within the project

Comment: I would not say you are "dead ended", but since you two are working on different OS's, it may best to create OS-specific package files, add them to the repo ignore list, and use the fs lib to normalize any file paths used in the code.